# How to see the fixes that a Build contains on a CAL Jira?

Tags: build

1. Open SF case for Product Support where the Build is released
2. Open CAL with issue type Hotfix Status that CAL must be at "to be sent" status as that confirms it was QA validated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open SF case for Product Support where the Build is released
2. Open CAL with issue type Hotfix Status that CAL must be at "to be sent" or "closed" status as that confirms it was QA validated.